# How to remove \' from each array element in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm taking values from hidden fields present on my form using jQuery. Each of these values are present within single quotes like **'enable'**. Now, I'm creating an array and pushing these values in it. I'm sending this array using javascript to a PHP file. I'm sending this array through jQuery AJAX method's url attrubute. The code for it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#disable_url', function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = new Array();

    $("input:checked:not(#ckbCheckAll)").each(function() {
      items.push($(this).val());
    });

    var str = $("#user_filter").serialize();    
    var str = decodeURIComponent(str);

    var user_status = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      user_status.push($("#"+items[i]).val());
    }    

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "manage_users.php?op=disable_bulk_users&items="+items+"&options="+str+"&user_status="+user_status,
      dataType: 'json',  
      success: function(data) {
        var redirect_link = data.href;
        window.location.href = redirect_link;
      }          
    });
  })
});
```

Now the PHP code snippet from manage_users.php is as follows:

```
$request = empty( $_GET ) ? $_POST : $_GET ;
  $op       = $request['op'];
  switch( $op ) {
    case "disable_bulk_users":
   /*I'm using explode here as I'm getting the comma separated list of strings and I want to convert it back into an array*/ 
    $user_ids = explode(',', $request['items']);
    $user_statuses = explode(',', $request['user_status']);
    print_r($user_statuses);
    die;
    break;
  }
```

If I print the array `$user_statuses` it prints as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => \'enable\'
    [1] => \'enable\'
    [2] => \'enable\'
    [3] => \'enable\'
    [4] => \'enable\'
    [5] => \'enable\'
    [6] => \'disable\'
    [7] => \'disable\'
    [8] => \'disable\'
    [9] => \'disable\'
    [10] => \'disable\'
    [11] => \'disable\'
    [12] => \'disable\'
    [13] => \'disable\'
    [14] => \'disable\'
    [15] => \'disable\'
    [16] => \'disable\'
    [17] => \'disable\'
    [18] => \'disable\'
    [19] => \'disable\'
)
```

Actually I want to remove the string **\'** occuring at the beginning and the string **\'** occuring at the end of each array element. Can you help me in getting the clean array after removal of these strings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I assume there's no way you can edit your form to remove the extra quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it client-side:

```
user_status.push($("#"+items[i]).val().replace(/'/g,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
function mytrim(&$item){
 $item = trim($item, "\'");
}
$array = array("\'test\'", "\'test2\'");

array_walk($array, "mytrim");
print_r($array);//Array ( [0] => test [1] => test2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

in php,

```
$data = array_map('stripslashes', $data);
```

or if you want to remove the quotes too

```
$data = array_map('trim', $data, ['\\\''])
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the "\'" from the string using string replace.
$status= str_replace("\'",'',$user_statuses);